# Filter emails by sender address format in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

For the past year I've been getting *a lot* of spam mail passing through the Outlook filter.

The spam emails are almost all unique in content and wording, but they have one thing in common: **the sender addresses are all on the format** `"X" <Y>` (where X and Y are placeholders).
This struck me as odd because I thought all email addresses had to be on the format `X@Y.Z`, but I guess not.

The spam address format may be weird but nevertheless it is predictable and I should easily be able to create a rule which looks for this pattern (regex). There are custom rules in Outlook but I can't seem to find any which can filter emails based on the format or content of the sender address (except for exact matches).

Does anyone know if there is any way or possibility to do this in Outlook? Or if I can use some third party service which can interact with Outlook?

Comment: Why not just add these to the Junk Email folder. Mark the emails as Junk. Over time there should be much less spam

Comment: @John I am. And I've continued doing so for a very long time but yet I see no difference :/

Comment: @Nermin， It has been a few days and just checking in to see if you seen the replies provided. You can try to accept a reply as answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The from address showing as `"X" <Y>` isn't all that unusual.

You're right that email addresses are always in the format of `<alias>@<domain>`, for instance `me@mydomain.com` but what you're seeing in Outlook is the `From:` address which is subtly different.

In order to allow the sender to include not only the email address that it is coming from, but also their name, the `From:` address includes both pieces of information. Depending on the email client, some only show the name, others show both, but within the email headers you'll find an entry similar to

`From: "My Name" <me@mydomain.com>`

To add to the confusion, the `From:` is only really used by the email client to display information to the user, it's not used for transmitting the actual email. That's handled via a separate header like `X-Envelope-From:` (though it can be different depending on your email setup) which might be the same as the `From:` address, but doesn't need to be.

Lots of senders use this to give each individual email a unique sending address, presumably for later tracking. For instance if you look at an Amazon email, you might find something like this

```
From: "Amazon.co.uk" <shipment-tracking@amazon.co.uk>
X-Envelope-From: 202092526543228000182c45fb07fec0p0eu-C398VG95LVI@bounces.amazon.co.uk
```

The former being what shows up in Outlook, the latter being what the mailserver looks at when handling the email.

As such, while I've never tested it, I'm not even sure the `From:` address has to contain an RFC valid email address, so long as there's a valid `X-Envelope-From:` address there.

So if you want to make sure you're filtering out those messages, you may find you need to find and add the `X-Envelope-From:` address rather than the visible `From:` address. Certainly when adding addresses to the allowed lists to circumvent spam screening at the server level, I've found that adding `*@amazon.co.uk` won't have the desired effect, but adding `*@bounces.amazon.co.uk` does.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know if there is any way or possibility to do this in Outlook?

Not feasible in Outlook to filter emails based on email address pattern or format. No built-in options available in Outlook for this and I don't aware of any 3rd-party plugin can be used for this need either. Nevertheless, even if it's supported, I don't think filtering out emails sent by addresses with the patter "X" < Y > can work perfectly, as based on my experience, some legit external mails may also with this sender email address format, like "DisplayName" < xxx@outlook.com >:
[image]

With the above being said, agree with Keith that you can take a further look at the [message headers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-internet-message-headers-in-outlook-cd039382-dc6e-4264-ac74-c048563d212c), especially check the field like "`Return-Path`" or "`X-Envelope-From`" and see if there's any consistent keyword can be used in a rule.

To view the message headers, you can leverage the Message Header Analyzer tool: https://mha.azurewebsites.net/

If you managed to locate a qualified keyword for it, you can try setting up a rule similar to below:
[image]

Suppose the above cannot work out as expected, another thought I come up with is to make the Junk email filter more aggressive by changing the level of protection in Outlook:
[image]

Moreover, aside from keeping manually moving these mails to Junk Email folder, a more effective way to make MS aware of this kind of spam mails is to **Report** them via the [Report Message addin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-report-message-add-in-b5caa9f1-cdf3-4443-af8c-ff724ea719d2) (But this may require an M365 email account）